# Managing a large collection of PDF files

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have a large collection of PDF files and am looking forward to an application that:

- Is easy to install (Available in repositories)
- Is portable (migration to other computer running linux or windows should be easy)
- Allows annotating and tagging/ categorizing the PDFs
- Allows searching the text of PDFs, metadata, annotations, tags, etc.
- Allows batch import of PDFs
- Also allows importing PDFs without requiring to copy the physical files
- Is preferably open-source
- Allows backing up of library on-line

Any suggestions? Please mention if your suggestion does not have any features mentioned above.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/which-pdf-viewer-would-you-recommend?rq=1)

Comment: @Anwar the question discusses PDF readers. I am looking more at PDF managers (Rhythmbox vs. music player that takes a filename as an input and plays it).

Comment: Being portable is not very easy as Windows programs != Linux programs. You can try to find one that is available for both systems and can share a library.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS it should be easy to (at least) move form Computer A running Distribution A of linux to Computer B running Flavor B :)

Comment: Cross distro is a bit easier if you use a tar.gz installation archive. It will be harder to Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Calibre*](http://calibre-ebook.com/) and [*Mendeley*](http://www.mendeley.com/) would come to mind. Nr. 1 is in the [official repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/calibre), Nr. 2 available as a [*.deb* package](http://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu/instructions/). Both are cross-platform and fulfill most of your requirements.

Another viable option might be [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/). [Here's a comparison to Mendeley](http://hlwiki.slais.ubc.ca/index.php/Zotero_vs._Mendeley).

Comment: Very impressed with Zotero. Does the job very well.

Comment: Indeed, it does! I just love its integration with Chrome and LibreOffice.