# Document Viewer (Evince) history navigation

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, pdf, evince, navigation

I am satisfied with basic functionality of *Evince* (3.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04). Unfortunately in this viewer I am really missing history navigation i.e. possibility to go back to previous views and optionally go forward in the viewing history like most of the web browsers have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. I think this function is very important when using hyperlinks and searching during browsing.

For *Evince* I did not find this function on the standard keyboard shortcuts, in the menu, in the documentation.

Does *Evince* have this function and how can it be used?

Which other PDF viewers maintained for *Ubuntu* have this function?

Comment: You want to click on a link which takes you to another part of the same pdf file and then navigate back to where you were? I just looked at the pdf viewers that are part of Firefox and Chrome. Looks like they don't have this feature either. Or if they do, I didn't come across it. Would be a handy feature to have.

Comment: @vasa1: Yes, this is the most frequent use case - to return to the link. Also sometimes when I use search I would like to return to the original location later. I know that Adobe Reader for Windows has this function but I would prefer using a more lightweight viewer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under Evince 3.4 you can activate a "back" button by editing the toolbar (*Edit* → *Toolbar*; drag and drop functions to toolbar):

[image]

I don't think there's any hotkey by default but you might be able to add a [custom](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/shortcuts.html.en) one.

If you're looking for customization you might be better off with a PDF viewer like [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) or [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) anyway. Both should offer the function you're searching for.

Comment: Thank you! The back button has a different behaviour in comparison to page history in web browsers but it is very useful. Unfortunately the procedure for adding keyboard shortcuts works for menu items only. I will test the two recommended viewers.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning qpdfview! It allows setting the page background color. That's a feature I was missing.

Comment: `qpdfview` is great, but it doesn't have smooth scrolling like evince (3.10) has. How can one browse history with evince 3.10? Edit->Toolbar does not exist any more.

Comment: @Bach Would love to check if there's another way to do this in evince, but I am still on Ubuntu 12.04, sorry. Chances are the GNOME devs have done away with this feature. That seems to be their modus operandi these days :/.

Comment: I don't think the `back` button is available in Evince 3.10

Comment: alas, [this does not work with toolbar buttons](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1526432)

Comment: In newer versions of Evince -- I'm using 3.16.1 -- the back button is automatically part of the tool bar and no longer configurable. See picture in this other answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/372611/56280. However, there isn't any keyboard shortcut as far as I know.

Comment: I see no back button in 3.18.2.

Comment: The back button does not work.

Answer (score 18):

As of Evince 3.32, the key bindings are <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. I cannot find the toolbar button anymore.

Reference: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/770

Comment: Thanks. I just found it listed under the new `Keyboard Shortcuts` menu option after clicking the "Hamburger" button. It also indicates there that <kbd>Back</kbd> and <kbd>Forward</kbd> can be used, but I can't see these on my keyboard.

Comment: Can these be mapped to Alt + -> and Alt + <-?

Answer (score 10):

**Ubuntu 20.10**

Things have flipped around now, it's so much fun:

- Evince 3.38 history is working fine, notably with the Alt+P/Alt+N shortcuts (but I discovered that their header only search is useless: [How to find/search for text results only in the Outline/headers in PDFs open in Evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315324/how-to-find-search-for-text-results-only-in-the-outline-headers-in-pdfs-open-in/1315781#1315781) so I still can't use it daily)
- Okular 20.08 history is completely broke with Alt+Shift+Left/Right, possibly: https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg489269.html

I'll still go crazy one of these days.

I've made a minimal test file for this now: https://github.com/cirosantilli/media/blob/master/multipage_refs/multipage_refs.pdf

**Annoying Evince history bugs**

These have haunted me for years, including Ubuntu 18.04, Evince 3.28.2,  and make the history jump back feature unusable for the technical documents I read all day:

- the history jump does not jump to the expected location of a sane human:

  - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/399
  - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/558
  - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/810
- there was no default (`Alt+Left`) shortcut / it is not documented / I don't have the patience to find out how to create it: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/770

  Tha bug was fixed in Evince 3.32 as mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1150128/52975 and as of 3.34.1-1 I have a "Keyboard Shortcuts" menu entry that shows "Alt + P" and "Alt +N" as the shortcuts.

  However, possibly due to the aforementioned history bugs, the feature is still useless to me, e.g. if I visit https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/fa/DDI0487F_a_armv8_arm.pdf and click a table of contents link, Alt + P does nothing instead of jumping back to the table of contents as expected.

You should go and upvote them.

**Best solution I've found for Ubuntu 20.04**

Use Okular. It has a default jump at Alt + Shift + Left/Right, and other key features like searching in the Table of Contents (or at least has them in a place I can easily find).

**Best solution I've found for Ubuntu 18.04**

Use Firefox!: [What PDF viewers are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/what-pdf-viewers-are-available-for-ubuntu/1085859#1085859) Okular was buggy there too, I forgot why now.

Comment: `Alt` + `P` or `N` works for me in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the `xpdf` viewer for this reason. It has history navigation and is quite lightweight and rapid. It is available for ~any system running X11.

Answer (score 0):

At present (Ubuntu 18.04; Linuxmint 19.1) Xreader (version 2.0.2) offers functionality go back and forward in the viewing history.

Comment: Xreader has own bugs, like accidental autoscrolling(I tried every pdf reader like atril, evince, xreader, qv)