# How can I reenable the back button in Evince on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, evince

Cannot find the back button in Evince 3.10.0, Ubuntu 13.10.

There used to be a back button which can be added to the menu bar. It simply offers the ability to jump back from url in the pdf. Now its gone :(

Anyone know how to get it back?

Comment: What do you mean with "the ability to jump back from url in the pdf"? If I click a link in evince it opens up the browser with that url, it doesn't open the url inside evince

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio I assume they're referring to internal hyperlinks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm seeing a back button in Evince 3.10.0-0ubuntu2 in Ubuntu 13.10:

[image: Go to previous history item - Evince]