# How to find/search for text results only in the Outline/headers in PDFs open in Evince?

Tags: pdf, evince

Okular 20.8 and earlier has a feature that I miss badly: the ability to search for results only in the header titles, AKA "Outline" tab in the Evince UI.

But in Evince 3.38, I don't see any search box specific for the Outline, and if I do the using Ctrl + F, it just opens a regular full text search that finds hits anywhere in the document, not only in headers.

In Okular, as I start typing the search box of their outline, it filters only the headers which match the search string, which is very handy.

Created a feature request for it at: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1555

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Not possible, afaik. Would be a valid feature request.

Comment: @vanadium done at: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1555

Comment: @vanadium BTW, it is possible, but the feature is almost useless for other reasons mentioned below :)

Answer (score 0):

**Just type the search directly without Ctrl + F**

Ermmm, you just give focus to the outline, e.g. by selecting any random header, and  start typing your search term directly, without Ctrl + F, then a little search box appears at the bottom.

However, as of 3.38, unlike Okular the search, it:

- only matches from the very first title character
- does not filter matching headers only, you have to hit up/down arrow keys several times to navigate/find them
- does not find in nested headers that are currently closed

These limitations make the feature mostly unusable for complex documents for me as mentioned at: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1555#note_1032850 Here's a good test document: https://ia800404.us.archive.org/27/items/linux-insides/linux-insides.pdf