# When executing acroreader it fails with "error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file"

Tags: adobe-reader

I have downloaded adobe reader 9.5.5 and installed it using gdebi.Now if I  click on any  pdf it is not starting.I tried "acroread" in terminal and it is showing me this error

```
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I have installed libxml2.But still it is showing the same above error. My system OS is ubuntu 13.10.

Is there any solution to my problem for using Adobe reader or any other alternative pdf reader other than foxit and default(evince) or okular  by using which  I can highlight any text in my pdf?

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/which-pdf-viewer-would-you-recommend) are meny Pdf Viewers. But in Evince, I can highlight text.(Not Images). Even Open URLs.

Comment: I would recommend **PDF-XChange-Viewer** (under Wine) but perhaps you don't want it because it's like Foxit, just a little better.

Answer (score 50):

I resolved this issue on my 64 bits Ubuntu (13.10) using the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: That solved mine too on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: This also solved it for me on Ubuntu 16.10 64bit

Comment: Worked for me on Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia - Cinnamon

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 17.10 64bit too!

Comment: Me as well 17.10 64-bit

Comment: works for 18.04 64bit also

Comment: For 18.04 64 bit I had to install these libraries in addition to the above: libgtk2.0-0:i386 and libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386, then it worked

Comment: Worked for 19.04 64-bit as well

Comment: works for Debian 10

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 19.1 Mate 1.22.2

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is an issue with symbolic link to the correct version.

Identify the library dependency of your program and locate the library like this (I don't have acroread, but should be same):

```
$ which evince
/usr/bin/evince
$ ldd /usr/bin/evince | grep libxml
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xb7534000)
$ ls -l /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jul 16 20:48 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so -> libxml2.so.2.7.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jul 16 20:48 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.7.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1360484 Jul 16 20:48 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
```

If you do not have symlink named libxml2.so.2 pointing somewhere, create one:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
```

Change evince to acroread in your case.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This ldd command does not list libxml anywhere in the output; for acroread I get the output "        not a dynamic executable".  Suggestions?

Comment: The acroread is a shell script, the binary can be found under /opt/Adobe/Reader9/intellinux/bin, which shows the list with ldd

Answer (score 0):

This also resolved it for me in Debian Buster using the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote [answers you like](https://askubuntu.com/a/410648/), which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This link https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+question/209800, post #23 and #24 can also help to solve this issue. I successfully applied both on Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-45-generic

```
$ sudo updatedb; locate libBIB
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIB.so
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIB.so.1.2
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIBUtils.so
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIBUtils.so.1.1

$ ldd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread | grep not
libBIB.so => not found
libBIBUtils.so => not found
libACE.so => not found
libAGM.so => not found
libCoolType.so => not found
libAXE8SharedExpat.so => not found
libJP2K.so => not found
libAdobeXMP.so => not found
libicuuc.so.36 => not found
libResAccess.so => not found


$ sudo updatedb; locate libBIBUtils.so
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIBUtils.so
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIBUtils.so.1.1

$ cd /usr/lib
$ sudo ln -s /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIB.so .
$ sudo ln -s /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIB.so.1.2 .
$ sudo ln -s /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIBUtils.so .
$ sudo ln -s /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libBIBUtils.so.1.1 .
```