# What programs can edit rich text fields in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I've been using Document Viewer to fill out a PDF that has editable fields. It's been working okay with one exception. I would like to use rich text in some of the fields. Nothing too fancy, just bold a fiew things and maybe mess with the font and text size.

Are there any other programs that will allow me to use rich text while filling out a PDF form?

Edit: I've been trying to get LibreOffice Draw to work... but it doesn't support embed fronts which is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found some leads - haven't used any of these myself:

- [Master PDF Editor for Linux](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor) seems the most promising
- [Install the latest version of the Adobe Reader in Ubuntu or wine](https://askubuntu.com/q/1047686/301745)
- [Adobe Reader for Linux](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/) hasn't been supported since 2013
- [pdftk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pdftk.1.html) seems to be more of a batch processing tool

Let me know if any of them work for you.

Also the PDF needs to support "rich text formatting" in form fields. [Source](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/917765)

Comment: IMO using Google Docs is a better solution than these examples. Master PDF is commercial software but also closed source so who knows what it's doing to your system. The same goes for Adobe Reader and using `wine` can cause problems as much as I love the software.

Comment: @Kris I just tried opening a form PDF in Docs but it destroyed the formatting. If you could post an answer explaining how to use it, that would be great.