# "To view the full contents of this document, you need a later version of the PDF viewer"

Tags: evince

Unfortunately document viewer only shows me this if I open my PDF document:

[image]

If I enter the Adobelink there is no linux version of acrobate reader. I need to open and write some stuff into this document.

Comment: check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/which-pdf-viewer-would-you-recommend

Comment: i seriously think you should include a screenshot without the names of  your clients....

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 6):

This document appears to use functions not available in the default PDF viewer (Evince) that you are using. Adobe has long stopped maintaining Reader for Linux, and removed the download links.

However, if you read [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/adobe-reader-linux-download-pulled-website), it is still possible to install Adobe Reader for Ubuntu. The .deb file can be found [here](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb). Hopefully, it will offer the functionality that this document requires.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know about the OP, but for me this is the solution to the documents I couldn't open in okular, xpdf, evince, epdfview, mupdf, gv...

Answer (score 1):

I have `qpdfview` installed. It's pretty fast and featured enough. It's got different view modes like 2 pages, 4 pages, etc. and also docks changeable thumbnails, outline etc. And unlike `Okular` which is also a great pdf reader, `qpdfview` doesn't depend on much to be installed; Okular  requires some amount of kde packages. To install the latest stable:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:b-eltzner/qpdfview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qpdfview
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't help with Adobe's "broken" documents that want you to download the latest reader from Adobe directly :-/