# Disable color printing from `Document Viewer`

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf, canon, colors

In `Document Viewer` version 3.10.03, is the color printing capability a function of the driver or a function of `Document Viewer` itself?

I want to print black only but when hunt for a way to disable color printing in `File > Color` I see this `Printer Profile: Unspecified Profile`. There does not appear to be any way to disable color printing, at least on this tab.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. The file is a .PDF. The driver is for the [Canon PIXMA MX494](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx494.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=LINUX) which was the closest match I found for the actual printer which is an MX492.

Comment: I found this (more recent) answer particularly useful.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1078735/200503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print monochrome go to `File > Print > Advanced`. Enabling `greyscale` seems to disable color printing.

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.18: `File > Print > Color > Print Color as Gray > On`