# Highlight words in Document Viewer

Tags: pdf, document

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.10. I need to highlight some sentences and/or paragraphs for easy searching but I can't find any option for this in the "Document Viewer" which is the default application for pdf files.

Comment: I use okular for that.

Comment: Then what is the best and lightweight application for this?

Comment: i prefer foxit it's simple to use and if you install on windows mac or any mobile keep the highlighting and attachments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I highlight or annotate PDFs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-or-annotate-pdfs)

Comment: Re "Possible duplicate" reports - The landscape of programs might've changed a lot in the intervening 6 years since those threads, or I hope it has... so I think it's valid to reevaluate the question.

Comment: @underscore_d offer a bounty on it. It's a standard bounty reason: "The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision …"

Comment: @muru Fair point, I didn't know about that, and using that to update an existing question would be tidier than having a new one every N years :-)

Comment: @underscore_d  I updated my "Document Viewer" answer to [How can I highlight or annotate PDFs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-or-annotate-pdfs) 6 weeks ago.

Comment: `Ctrl + H`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437335/evince-keyboard-shortcut-to-highlight-text

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Document Viewer DOES actually support annotations and highlightings in PDF files (not in other formats). Just click on that notebook like button and you'll be able to annotate and highlight text.

[image]

Comment: You will be able to highlight but not delete the highlights :(

Comment: @GStav You can right click on the highlighted text and select `Remove annotation`. You can also right click and select `Annotation properties` and change colour etc.

Comment: THIS MUST BE MOST UPVOTED ANSWER

Comment: Does anyone knows the keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: @NVSAbhilash I read somewhere that the key bindings are `s` for sticky notes and `Ctrl+h` (or at least will be in a future release).

Comment: short and simple. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try Mendeley (https://www.mendeley.com/)! It does the work like a charm!

In fact, Mendeley is more than a PDF-reader. You can use it to organize your docs and references.

Answer (score 1):

Document Viewer doesn't support highlighting install [another application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/which-pdf-viewer-would-you-recommend) such as FoxIt Reader. I prefer foxit because it's simple to use and if you install on Windows, Mac or mobile keep the highlighting and attachments.

**To install foxit reader** :

1. Open Foxit [website](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/).
2. Click "Free download" and it will detect operating system then click "Download". [image]
3. Extract the file you downloaded.
4. Double click the **.run** file and install.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use the WPS it's great tool for pdf reader and supports highlighting function in pdf files.
https://www.wps.com/linux

Answer (score 0):

In the default document viewer that comes with Ubuntu, you can use `ctrl`+`H` to highlight the text.

Answer (score 0):

In the hamburger menu in the top right there is a "keyboard shortcuts" menu which shows `ctrl+h` as shortcut to highlight

[image]