# Alternatives to Adobe Reader/Editor?

Tags: pdf, alternative, adobe-acrobat

So the wife is on her last straw with Windows 10, and I want to switch her to Ubuntu. She uses Reader for her Girl Scouts/Guides PDF work, just basic text changes and entering.

**The question is:**
Does she even need Adobe Reader or are there programs that she can use to read and alter on Ubuntu that work just as well?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  Try searching for PDF reader on Ask Ubuntu or for Ubuntu PDF reader on Google.  You will doubtless find many possible options.

Comment: ^it depends on the type of PDF forms she's given, unfortunately.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/907080/the-search-for-the-ultimate-pdf-viewer

Comment: I figured the question had been asked a million times prior it's just finding the badly worded tags and headers that people put up with little thought so the answers aren't linked . Most of what comes up isn't relevant in a lot of ways because of this . 
I found this as a starter if anyone else finds this : https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/?-update&x&ver=3710  .