# PDF Viewer for Embedded Linux

Tags: pdf

I am looking for an open source/proprietary (open source preferred) PDF viewer(No editing required) to use in an HMI that runs Embedded Linux. The goal is to view manuals and other such files in the display. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What PDF viewers are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/what-pdf-viewers-are-available-for-ubuntu) See the "Lightweight" section of the accepted answer.

Comment: @user535733 No, it's a Linux distro custom made for that specific HMI

Comment: @karel Thanks a lot. I can definitely try one of these.

Comment: @House If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.